Resource on predicting trade patterns at the individual level
This is a behavioral question, but is applied to quantitative finance. Are there any resources on measuring/predicting trade patterns at the individual level. So if I am a financial broker, dealer, alternative-market etc and have access to individual client data and their past & current trades, what types of modelling has been researched in literature? Resources would be greatly appreciated as I can't find much on this topic...
An example of what I am after is something like: if a client is long with a stop-loss at $\\\$84$, and they have never amended or removed their stop-loss, well we have a high degree of certainty their minimum sell order (closing position) will about $\\\$84.$ Or if someone always closes their position with an average of $3\%$ profit and loss, where the variance of the take-profit/loss is $0.1\%$, then we know it's quite likely they close their position $ \pm 3\%$. Or they always close with draw-down of X etc
So with this individual data, we take the collection of the clients and will be able predict their positions in the future given X price and market conditions in the future
